# c# substring Error - StartIndex cannot be less than zero

Tags: c#, substring

I have a string called value with `1899-12-30 01:30:00`

I want to get 01:30 into a seperate string, I have tried to use substring but it keeps giving me an error that the startindex cannot be less than zero, can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

```
using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);

            }
            excel_con.Close();


            if (dtExcelData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (DataRow rw in dtExcelData.Rows)
                {
                    //Creates StaffID
                     rw["StaffID"] = "00" + rw["Host Key of Staff"].ToString();

                    //Get duration out of DateTime
                     string Value = rw["Taught Periods Distinct as duration"].ToString();
                     string Duration = Value.Substring(Value.Length - 10, 5);

                     rw["Taught Periods Distinct as duration"] = Duration.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Debugging it says:

*Duration = "01:30" Type String

Value = "30/12/1989 01:30:00" Type String

Value.Length = 19 Type int

rw["Taught periods as distinct as duration"] = "30/12/1989 01:30:00" Type object {string}*

Comment: Are you sure about what `Value` is.  The error indicates that it has a length less than 10.

Comment: are you sure, Value contains `1899-12-30 01:30:00`?

Comment: Are you sure the Value has that value?

Comment: Isn't `rw["Taught Periods Distinct as duration"]` a `DateTime`? Perhaps you could just cast it to `DateTime` and be done with it? And, well, the message is quite obvious - `Value.Length - 10` must add up to a value lower than zero - `Value` doesn't seem to contain the string you think it contains.

Comment: what is `rw["..."]`? Are you sure that `Value` has the value `1899-12-30 01:30:00`? Can you show that code?

Comment: I agree with Luaan. This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me. Use DateTime methods to deal with date time.

Comment: You need to show us / define what `rw` is and how you are assigning properties to it. It looks like it's supposed to be a Dictionary, but your code example doesn't have enough detail. Perhaps you forgot to assign `rw["Taught Periods..."]` with the contents of `value`?

Comment: updated question now to include more code and debugging results,  This is being populated by importing excel into datatable.

Comment: @Redheadinferno, May be it at the end of loop that you are getting invalid value in `Value`, for your values from debugger, you will get invalid result, but not an exception.

Comment: what does this mean Habib?

Comment: @Redheadinferno, the debugging values you have shown in your answer could be  at the start of your iteration in `foreach` loop. The values in question shouldn't throw an exception. They will return invalid value for duration which should look something like : `"9 01:3"` there shouldn't be any exception.

Comment: oh right so some data in that loop is causing the problem.  Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First add a break point and see the value of `Value`, it seems like there is invalid value in your variable.

To extract out `01:30` into a separate string, a **better approach** would be to use `DateTime` parsing. Because your string is a valid `DateTime` value. Use

```
DateTime parsedDateTime;
string Duration = null;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact("1899-12-30 01:30:00", //or rw["Taught Periods Distinct as duration"].ToString();
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out parsedDateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid date");
}
else
{
    Duration = parsedDateTime.ToString("HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: Parsing to DateTime is definitely a better approach than substring. By doing that you can use parsedDateTime.Minute, parsedDateTime.Second...

Comment: I cant get this to work when I uncomment rw["Taught Periods Distinct as duration"]

Comment: All that parsing and converting is not necessary. Excel stores dates and times directly in a native data format, so you can directly access the date and time components without needing to convert them to strings. This leads only to problems (like with different regional settings) *[I never downvote]*

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you want to extract the time (hour + minute) from your date.

For this, I recommend not to do string conversions. Instead, better use a more direct approach by directly using `DateTime`, like this:

```
DateTime Value = rw["Taught Periods Distinct as duration"];
rw["Taught Periods Distinct as duration"] = Value.TimeOfDay ;
```

Answer (score -4):

this works:

```
string Value = "Taught Periods Distinct as duration".ToString();
string Duration = Value.Substring(Value.Length - 10, 5);
```

and also:

```
string Value2 = "1899-12-30 01:30:00";
string Duration2 = Value2.Substring(Value2.Length - 10, 5);
```

Comment: The OP is not trying to get a substring from that string.  They are using that as an index to get another value that they want the substring of.

Comment: `"Taught Periods Distinct as duration"` is clearly an indexer into some sort of collection.  It's not the string the OP is trying to extract the time from.